# Asignar un valor a una variable global después de obtenerla de un servicio en angular

Tags: nodejs, angular, typescript

Hay alguna manera de asignar un valor globalmente después de una función subscribe para que se use en todo mi componente?

Tengo un servicio tal que así:

```
import { NumberInput } from '@angular/cdk/coercion';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { Candidato } from "../interfaces/candidato";
import { Cuestionario } from '../interfaces/cuestionario';
import { Respuesta } from '../interfaces/Respuesta';
import { Verdaderos } from '../interfaces/verdaderos';
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class CandidateService {

  url="http://localhost:3000/api"

  constructor(private http:HttpClient) { }



  getPersona(ID:Number):Observable<Candidato[]>{
    return this.http.get<Candidato[]>(this.url + "/persona/searchrh/"+ID)
  }

  deletePersona(ID_RH:Number,ID:Number){
    return this.http.delete<Respuesta>(this.url+"/persona/deleteRH/"+ID_RH+"/"+ID)
 }

  getCandidato(ID:Number):Observable<Candidato>{
    return this.http.get<Candidato>(this.url + "/persona/search/"+ID)
  }

  getCuestionarioRespuestas(ID:Number):Observable<Verdaderos[]>{
    return this.http.get<Verdaderos[]>(this.url + "/cuestionario/"+ID)
  }
}
```

Con una interfaz de este estilo:

```
export interface Verdaderos{
    Pregunta: number;
}
```

Lo que obtengo del método getCuestionarioRespuestas es un array con todas las respuestas de un tipo desde mi backend y la base de datos (el proyecto es un cuestionario) y pretendo separar el número de la pregunta respondida para así sacar un score individual para poder graficarlo con ngx-charts

De forma que en este método separo y cuento por categorías.

```
getRespuestasCandidato(ID: Number) {
    this.Persona.getCuestionarioRespuestas(ID).subscribe((data:Verdaderos[]) =>{
      this.conteo = data;
      this.numbers = this.conteo.map(x => x.ID_Pregunta);
      console.log(this.numbers)

      const N2 = this.N1.filter(x => this.numbers.includes(x));
      const countN2 = N2.length;
      console.log(countN2)

      const M2 = this.M1.filter(x => this.numbers.includes(x));
      const countM2 = M2.length;
      console.log(countM2)

      const P2 = this.P1.filter(x => this.numbers.includes(x));
      const countP2 = P2.length;
      console.log(countM2)
      this.N = countN2;
      this.M = countM2;
      this.P = countP2
    })
  }
```

La forma de separarlos y de poder graficarlos están globalmente

```
N: number = 0;
  M: number = 0;
  P: number = 0;
  M1: Number[] = [3,6,9,12,15,18,21,24,27,30,33,36,39,42,45,48,51,54,57,60,63,66,69,72,75,78,81,84,87,90];
  N1: Number[] = [2,5,8,11,14,17,20,23,26,29,32,35,38,41,44,47,50,53,56,59,62,65,68,71,74,77,80,83,86,89]; 
  P1: Number[] = [1,4,7,10,13,16,19,22,25,28,31,34,37,40,43,46,49,52,55,58,61,64,67,70,73,76,79,82,85,88];

NE = 100 - this.N- this.M- this.P

single = [
    {
      "name": "Narcisismo",
      "value": this.N    },
    {
      "name": "Maquiavelismo",
      "value": this.M
    },
    {
      "name": "Psicopatia",
      "value": this.P
    },
    {
      "name": "No evaluado",
      "value": this.NE
    }
  ];
```

Pero no he podido asignarlos para que el array single obtenga los valores del método getRespuestasCandidato. Cabe mencionar que dicho método lo mando a llamar dentro de ngAfterViewInit. Sospecho que mi lógica está mal, o el cálculo y la separación de las categorías debería hacerse en backend. De todas formas, si pudiera signar el valor a las variables después del método para así graficar, ya solo es cuestión de las variables, pero no he hallado la forma apropiada

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Para asignar valores globales en un componente de Angular, puedes utilizar una variable de instancia del componente.

Por ejemplo, en tu componente puedes declarar tus variables N, M y P como variables de instancia del componente y luego asignarles los valores que obtienes en el método getRespuestasCandidato:

```
export class TuComponente {
  N: number = 0;
  M: number = 0;
  P: number = 0;
  M1: Number[] = [3,6,9,12,15,18,21,24,27,30,33,36,39,42,45,48,51,54,57,60,63,66,69,72,75,78,81,84,87,90];
  N1: Number[] = [2,5,8,11,14,17,20,23,26,29,32,35,38,41,44,47,50,53,56,59,62,65,68,71,74,77,80,83,86,89];
  P1: Number[] = [1,4,7,10,13,16,19,22,25,28,31,34,37,40,43,46,49,52,55,58,61,64,67,70,73,76,79,82,85,88];
  conteo: Verdaderos[] = [];
  numbers: Number[] = [];

  constructor(private Persona: CandidateService) {}

  getRespuestasCandidato(ID: Number) {
    this.Persona.getCuestionarioRespuestas(ID).subscribe((data:Verdaderos[]) =>{
      this.conteo = data;
      this.numbers = this.conteo.map(x => x.ID_Pregunta);
      console.log(this.numbers)

      const N2 = this.N1.filter(x => this.numbers.includes(x));
      const countN2 = N2.length;
      console.log(countN2)

      const M2 = this.M1.filter(x => this.numbers.includes(x));
      const countM2 = M2.length;
      console.log(countM2)

      const P2 = this.P1.filter(x => this.numbers.includes(x));
      const countP2 = P2.length;
      console.log(countM2)
      this.N = countN2;
      this.M = countM2;
      this.P = countP2
    })
  }
}
```

Luego, puedes utilizar las variables N, M y P en cualquier parte del componente, por ejemplo, para mostrar el valor en una etiqueta HTML:

```
<p>Valor de N: {{N}}</p>
<p>Valor de M: {{M}}</p>
<p>Valor de P: {{P}}</p>
```